# Use of classifier tag in Maven dependencyManagement

Tags: java, maven

Good morning,

I am working on a multi-module Maven project in which child modules inherit from a parent  information regarding dependencies, this is done with the `<dependencyManagement>` tag.

I am now trying to import the following library:

```
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
```

following this way:

**Parent pom**

```
     <dependencyManagement>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>${version.json-lib}</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
         </dependency>
     </dependencyManagement>
```

**child pom**

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I thought this could be enough as the dependency management section of the parent should take care of making inheritable all necessary information, but this is not the case.

In particular I always get

> 'dependencies.dependency.version' for net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar is missing.

while using `mvn clean install` command.

I have tried adding `classifier` tag also on child pom and it seems to work, but it seems to me like a dirty workaround also because I have now classifier information duplicated both in parent and child pom (If I delete the classifier information from parent, Maven cannot find the dependency again).

I searched the net for a while and found no proper or clear documentation about this, can someone clear this out a bit please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is that if you define a dependency in child pom as you did...the default type is `jar` and **without** classifier ... as you can see in the error message `:jar` is missing... So you have to give the classifer at the dependency as well...

Comment: Hence there is no way to avoid the duplication basically?

Comment: In that particular case no. Apart from that I would strongly recommend to use more recent tools/dependencies because the jar's you are referencing is of 2010! There are much more newer versions available ... Having a dependency which is only vaild for JDK1.5 is very out of time...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers, about the version I know it's out of time, I am carrying on a really big refactor work on the project, hence I will update it asap! Thanks again :)